# How to import aliases in my TCSH script

Tags: sh, tcsh

I think everything is in the title.
I write a simple tcsh script, and I would like to use the aliases from my ~/.cshrc in it.
How can I do that ? 
I saw that there is a solution in bash with expand, but I will like to find the same for tcsh.
Best,

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this at the beginning?

```
source ~/.cshrc
```